# Удаление кодеков из ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Пишу программу на с++ для микширования потоков аудио. Хочу удалить все ненужные кодеки из библиотеки ffmpeg, поскольку их инициализация занимает кучу времени(секунд 6). Как это сделать?

P.S. Или инициализировать не все, а только какую-то часть. Под Win7

Comment: По тому, что у меня mplayer с вполне полным ffmpeg запускается за четверть секунды, предположу, что надо их не удалять, а просто найти как не инициализировать (но лично я не разбираюсь в этом)

Comment: @andreymal, к сожалению, у меня их приходится инициализировать. Вот хотелось бы инициализировать только нужные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо регистрации всех кодеков (`avcodec_register_all()`) регистрируй только нужные: `avcodec_register()`. Сами кодеки имеют паттерн:

- `ff_XXX_encoder`
- `ff_XXX_decoder`

Помимо кодеков могут потребовать парсеры, BSF либо акселераторы, их паттерны и функции регистрации:

- `ff_XXX_parser` - `av_register_codec_parser()`
- `ff_XXX_bsf` - `av_register_bitstream_filter()`
- `ff_XXX_hwaccel` - `av_register_hwaccel()`

Перед регистрацией сделать `extern` переменной, например:

```
extern AVCodec ff_h264_decoder;
extern AVCodec ff_libx264_encoder;
...
avcodec_register(&ff_h264_decoder);
avcodec_register(&ff_libx264_encoder);
```

За справками, сюда: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/allcodecs_8c_source.html

Аналогичные действия могут быть применены к форматам и протоколам.

Ну или пересобрать только с тем, что нужно.

Answer (score 2):

вы можете использовать `configure with --disable-everything` и потом включить только то, что вам необходимо и сбилдить.

Подробнее о сборке ffmpeg'a [тут](http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/#build)

Comment: т.е. предлагаете собрать только с нужными кодеками?

Comment: @Dmitry именно так.

Comment: Библиотека, что мне нужна, все-таки слишком большая и инициализация идет долго. Есть программый путь решения? Функция в ffmpeg, которая будет инициализировать только часть кодеков?

Comment: @Dmitry что вам мешает просто пересобрать библиотеку? Она как раз станет меньше по размеру, и поставленную задачу вы решите.